# Calculation of XIRR in python

Tags: python, xirr

want to calculate XIRR function for some data, is there any python library which has the XIRR function.

I tried the numpy financial but it only has IRR function, is there any other way of calculating XIRR where I don't have to manually input the cashflow values dates related to those values

Comment: One Google search gave me this: https://pypi.org/project/xirr/. Maybe that helps.